# What is the wheel in the Guhyagarbha tantra?

Tags: tibetan-buddhism, tantra

I am starting to explore [Luminous Essence: A Guide to the Guhyagarbha Tantra](https://wisdomcompassion.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/Luminous-Essence-A-Guide-to-the-Guhyagarbha-Tantra.pdf), where in the first section on the "title", says:

> All phenomena of saṃsāra and nirvāṇa are inseparable with the enlightened state; **they dwell primordially as the eternal wheel of adornment of enlightened body, speech, and mind**.

Not knowing much Tibetan buddhism (yet), what is meant by the "wheel" exactly? And by the wheel of "adornment"? Finally, what does it mean to dwell **primordially**, what is the actual word used that is translated to primordial from Tibetan? Same with the word wheel, what is the Tibetan word for it and also what is it talking about more specifically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The wheel of adornment" or "the lotus garland" is a metaphor for the multiverse, the interpenetrating matrix of worlds that co-arise together with the sentient beings experiencing them according to their karmic and mental conditioning.

The "Enlightened body, speech, and mind" aka "the enlightened state" is the ultimate nature of the multiverse or the ultimate reality "behind" the various worlds/appearances.

"All phenomena of saṃsāra and nirvāṇa are inseparable with the enlightened state" because they exist as different perspectives on, or different interpretations of, the ultimate reality.

"they dwell primordially as eternal" etc. means despite being illusory they are innate to the ultimate reality. In other words, the ultimate reality by its very nature always appears as illusory phenomena, it exists through them, not apart from them.